# Trouble understanding increment operators with arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c, loops, operators

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around a concept in C regarding the use of the operator ++ and arrays. I know enough that ++ will increment a value, but I'm running into a code snippet that does not make any sense to me:

```
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
  {
    if(c < NUM_CHARS)
    {
      thisval = ++freqarr[c];
      if(thisval > maxval)
      {
        maxval = thisval;
      }
    }
```

the line `thisval = ++freqarr[c];` does not make a lot of sense to me.
Does it mean that thisval adds an additional index or value to the array?

I'm still new to C, so I'm not sure if this is common in C or not, if it's not or looked down upon, please let me know.

Comment: An arrays has a fixed size that you specify during definition. You cannot add an index to an array. You can only modify the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix `++` has lower precendence than `[]`, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence.  So this is equivalent to `thisval = ++(freqarr[c]);`.  It takes the `c`th element of the array, and increments that element, then assigns the new value to `thisval`.  Just like:

```
freqarray[c] = freqarray[c] + 1;
thisval = freqarray[c];
```

Answer (score 0):

The prefix `++` operator increments its operand, and the resulting expression has the incremented value.

So this line does two things:

- It increments the value of `freqarr[c]` which is a member of an array
- It assigned the incremented value of `freqarr[c]` to `thisval`

Answer (score 0):

I presume that `c` is defined as an `int` and `freqarr` is defined as an array. (It's generally best to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question).

The prefix `++` operator increments an object and yields the incremented value. `freqarr[c]` is an object. The fact that it happens to be an element of an array is not relevant here. It works the same way as it would if it were applied to a simple named variable.

Note that the indexing operator `[]` binds more tightly than `++`, so the expression `++freqarr[c]` is equivalent to `++(freqarr[c])`.